# Perfect scroll bar not working in Angular 4+

Tags: angular

I tried to install Perfectscrollbar for my angularapp in the following url [https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfect-scrollbar#ie-support][1] but it is not working in the app. It showing the following error
 perfect_scrollbar_1.default is not a constructor. The following code is used in the component

```
import  PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';
ngOnInit() {
    var ps = new PerfectScrollbar('.scroll');
}
```

but it is not working. I referred properly in systemjs.config.js too. I also tried with following code.`import * as  PerfectScrollbar from 'perfect-scrollbar';` it is also giving error. Please help me if any one knows.

Comment: system.js ? AFAIK angular uses webpack right ?